# Ratio of random variables and the expected ratio of the average

Tags: probability, expected-value, ratio

Suppose I have the following random variables $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$, their support is the natural numbers. $X_1$ and $Y_1$ as well as $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are not independent.

I am given that $E(X_1/Y_1 ) \leq b$ and $E(X_2 / Y_2) \leq b$. Is it necessary that also $E\left( (X_1 + X_2) / (Y_1 + Y_2) \right)\leq b$? Is there a proof or counter example?

Comment: Is $(X_1,Y_1)$ independent of $(X_2,Y_2)$ or not?

Comment: Assume for now they are. Both cases are of interest.

Comment: Let $(X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2)$ have equal chances of being $(18,9,0,1)$ and $(0,1,18,9),$ for example. We can take $b=1$ but $(X_1+X_2)/(Y_1+Y_2)=1.8\gt 1.$

Comment: Thanks! Nice counter example. I wonder if we restrict $X_i/Y_i$ to be proportions i.e., $X_i + X^*_i = Y_i$, if it holds.

Comment: Still does not hold, for example $(5, 10, 0, 1)$ and $(5, 10, 10, 10)$. The condition is satisfied and b = 0.5, yet $E ((X_1 + X_2) / (Y_1 + Y_2)) = 0.6$.